# Is it fair or appropriate to travel with single members of the opposite sex?

Tags: relationships

My partner and I are currently in a bit of a quandary.

If there were say 4 people travelling, two in a relationship and two not, and the two not in a relationship happen to be of the same sex, would it be fair to your partner to go on a trip within that group of people?

Now we've read some things and know what the typical juvenile response is to this, if there's no cheating then it is fine. Of course. But that is not always the point. If a member of the opposite sex asked me to spend the night at their place alone, and of course no sex involved, I would not do it, because it is plainly disrespectful to my partner to expect they tolerate that behaviour.

Now we are wondering if this situation is acceptably tolerable to a partner?

We are both quite young, one of us is later 20's and the potential traveler is early 20's, if that matters

Comment: I'm afraid, everyone has their own opinion on what is tolerable/fair/appropriate and what not. And this opinion might even change in different circumstances. So I guess it will be hard to find a definite answer to your question...

Comment: This entirely depends on what agreements you and your partner have with regards to boundaries.

Comment: This question would probably produce answers that are opinion-based, please edit your question to ask about a specific interpersonal issue- like how to communicate to those friends about boundaries or how to communicate or ask your partner about how you feel?

Comment: Only one person can answer what is appropriate in this case: your partner. Ask them. How should strangers on the net know

Comment: There's a pretty opinion free answer to this: whatever you agree on with your significant other is appropriate. Anything you have to hide or they feel pressured to agree to is not. (There's a lesson to be learned from how polyamerous couples discuss the boundaries they set, unlike how monogamous couples often end up guessing what the boundaries are.)

Comment: Slightly confused: are you and your partner "_the two in the relationship_" of the four people travelling? Or are you asking whether it's OK to be the fifth person in the group? If the latter, what relevance is there in the fact that the two not in a relationship are the same sex? (Is the point – not mentioned as far a I can see – that they're both the _opposite_ sex to you?)